# what are the permissions of a specific user in a database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

how can I find out to which AD groups my DB user belongs to?
I need to find out all the permissions that a specific user has in a database.

[image: the users groups and roles in my database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for all the permission paths that a given user, use sys.login_token and sys.user_token.

sys.login_token will give you all the AD groups that the current server principal is a member of that are also defined as logins. For example, if AD user [domain\user] is a member of [domain\group1] and [domain\group2] and only group1 is defined as a login, only group1 will show up in the list. sys.login_token will also list any server-level roles that the login is a member of.

sys.user_token is the same, except that everything is database scoped.

Since both views operate under the context of "current user", you'll need to impersonate someone else to find out their permissions. The syntax is easy enough:

```
execute as login = 'domain\user';
select * from sys.login_token;
select * from sys.user_token;
revert;
```

To get any permissions that have been granted to your user explicitly, check out the sys.database_permissions and sys.server_permissions.

```
select * from sys.database_permissions
where grantee_principal_id = user_id();

select * from sys.server_permissions
where grantee_principal_id = suser_id();
```

Lastly, if you don't want to go through trying to calculate all the permissions that you could pick up from various paths, take a look at sys.fn_my_permissions. Basic syntax is:

```
select * from sys.fn_my_permissions('dbo.table', 'object');
```

Answer (score 1):

USE **sys.fn_my_permissions**

```
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'DATABASE');
```

Returns a list of the effective permissions of the caller.

```
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions('ATLY', 'USER');
```

Returns a list of the effective permissions of the User called 'ATLY'.

Comment: Not quite for either. The first statement will return any database-level permissions that are granted to the current user. That is, if someone ran `grant select to [youruser]`, that permission would show up here. For the second, that will return any permissions granted to your user on the stated user. That is, you'll see things like 'impersonate' or 'control'. But to the point, it won't tell you anything about what the passed in user can and cannot do.

Comment: I just would like to add, for my own reference,that from inside a stored procedure with WEXECUTE AS OWNER, I use the following select if I need to know the permissions of the caller:    select database_user = USER_NAME(), [login] = SUSER_SNAME(), [original login]=ORIGINAL_LOGIN()